# What optical elements can you use to implement an S gate in practice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer

How do you implement an **S gate** using an optical element or combination of optical elements in the following 2 scenarios?

1. The S gate acts on a polarization qubit (polarization of a photon)
2. The S gate acts on a location qubit (spatial mode of a photon)

The S gate has the following matrix representation:
$$ S = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: That looks like a quarter wave plate for polarization.

Comment: Maybe some phase shift by $\pi/2$?